# Deploying war file into managed weblogic server to the given path location

Tags: ant, weblogic

I am using the Ant `wldeploy` task to deploy a war file.
It is working fine, but the war file path in the deployed server is set to something like

```
servers/myadminservername/upload/mywarfilename/app
```

Instead, I would like to set this path myself in the Ant buildfile.

Can any one please help me with that?

The task I am using for this is:

```
<wldeploy action="deploy" verbose="false" debug="true"
          name="ClientProfileSyncPortTypeImplV8"            
          source="${results.war.file.dir}/ClientProfileSyncPortTypeImplV8.war"
          upload="true" adminurl="t3://${serverip}:${port}"
          user="${admin_id}"
          password="${admin_pw}"
          usenonexclusivelock="${lock}"
          targets="${target_managed1}">
</wldeploy>
```

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue, did you ever find resolution?

Comment: In what way do you need to customize the path?

Comment: when deploying from the weblogic UI the ear is placed in servers/myadminservername/upload/mywarfilename/app-name  when using the wldeploy ant task with the deploy action, it is in servers/myadminservername/upload/mywarfilename/app/app-name

Answer (score 0):

I think you can edit the config.xml and specify the path of your deployment.

Answer (score 0):

The `upload`, `targets` and `stage` / `nostage` / `externalstage` attributes of the [wldeploy](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/programming/wldeploy.html) task give some control over where the deployment is made to.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting the app and the deploying it from ant, accepting the path it chooses. Now I can deploy and redeploy just fine.  It's really neither here nor there to me where the ear lives - I was just sad that when I deployed in the UI I couldn't redeploy using ant.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I have a partial solution for anyone who stumbles across this question

From the path: "domain/servers/myadminservername/upload/mywarfilename/app" you can change the first part of this (You can edit the "servers/myadminservername/upload") to go to any directory relative to the WLS domain.

Go to the Administrator Console (using:  serverIP:serverPort/console) and in the left hand side follow the tree:
environment -> servers -> (AdminServerName) -> Configuration -> Deployment -> Upload Directory Name

The "Upload Directory Name" can contain a path to a directory that is relative to the domain.

So at least "domain/servers/myadminservername/upload/mywarfilename/app" can become "domain/path_of_your_choice/mywarfilename/app"

Hope this helps someone