# Deploying WAR file on WebLogic Server using Ant and specified upload path

Tags: java, ant, weblogic, war

I am using the

```
  Ant wldeploy
```

task to deploy a Java Web Service, packaged as a WAR file, to a WebLogic Server. 
Everything is working as expected except the WAR file is being uploaded to WLDomain/AdminUploadLocation/warFileName/app/warFile.war

where

- WLDomain - name of my WebLogic Server Domain
- AdminUploadLocation - location to upload WAR files specified by Admin Server configuration
- warFileName - name of the war file as a directory
- app - directory named "app"
- warFile.war - the war file itself

I am wondering if anyone knows a way to make the WAR file be directly uploaded like so:
WLDomain/AdminUploadLocation/warFile.war

i.e. skip creating the directory structure: warFileName/app/

Comment: This question was also asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562406/deploying-war-file-into-managed-weblogic-server-to-the-given-path-location The short answer is that you probably need a different method of deployment to specify the path. HOWEVER, if you set the deployment to "nostage" then it will remain in its original location and won't be uploaded, so you can put the file wherever you want.

Comment: I looked at that post this morning. It isn't what I'm after (if you look I'm actually one of the people who has replied to that question). I am using nostage and I am aware that it will stay in it's original location but it is being uploaded to a location I do not want. I want to be able to specify to exclude the automatically created directories. Thanks anyway though...